# MySQL not allowed to write to file system

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, ubuntu-18.04, create-table

I am running a MariaDB server on my Ubuntu machine `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.44-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2`. When trying to create a new table in a custom datadir with `DATA DIRECTORY='/home/myuser/ext'`, the MySQL error log tells me

```
7f70acb77700  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
```

mysqld is running as mysql user:

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
30450 mysql     20   0  695572 206208  16432 S   0,0  1,3   0:43.48 mysqld
```

data directory is owned by mysql user:

```
$ ls -l
drwxr-xr-x 4 mysql  mysql     4096 Feb 13 11:16 ext
```

ownership and permissons on original datadir:

```
$ ll /var/lib/mysql/
total 1355856
drwxr-xr-x  7 mysql mysql       4096 Feb 13 12:00 ./
```

apparmor apparently is not intefering. content of `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld`

```
# This file is intensionally empty to disable apparmor by default for newer
# versions of MariaDB, while providing seamless upgrade from older versions
# and from mysql, where apparmor is used.
#
# By default, we do not want to have any apparmor profile for the MariaDB
# server. It does not provide much useful functionality/security, and causes
# several problems for users who often are not even aware that apparmor
# exists and runs on their system.
#
# Users can modify and maintain their own profile, and in this case it will
# be used.
#
# When upgrading from previous version, users who modified the profile
# will be promptet to keep or discard it, while for default installs
# we will automatically disable the profile.
```

`/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.mysqld` is nonexistent.

I am out of ideas here... What else could it be?

Comment: The OS account which is used for to start mysql daemon must have access rights in the filesystem.

Comment: How do I find out which user is starting the daemon? The server is starting as a service, so it is root, is it not?

Comment: Check permissions of each component of `/home/myuser/ext`.